# How to generate Coefficient >0 in lasso regression or any other method?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, linear-regression, coefficients, lasso-regression

I am running below code to generate all the coefficient positive:

```
from sklearn.linear_model import Lasso

pos = Lasso(positive=True)
pos.fit(X,y)
list(pos.coef_)
```

the above code give me positive coefficient or "0" but I need all to be positive with some positive impact.

**Requirement** = All Positive coefficient(Coefficient should not be Zero(0))

How can I perform above task?

Comment: You could try removing the factors where the regression coefficient is zero and then re-running the regression again (feature elimination). The value of zero has the effect of implicitly removing the feature from the regression, so this would have the same effect.

Comment: @JamesPhillips, Thanks for this but Is it possible for you to provide some example through some basic code?

Comment: As an example: we regress factors X1, X2 and X3 against Y as in the equation "Y = aX1 + bX2 + cX3". In this example the regression gives us values for the parameters a, b, and c with parameter c equal to 0.0. This means that no matter what we use for X3, the value of "c * X3" is zero every time and has no effect on our calculations.  We can simply remove X3 from the regression and have the same result as leaving it in.

Answer (score 1):

```
lasso = Lasso(alpha=1, positive=True)
lasso_coeff['Coefficient Estimates] = pd.Series(lasso.coef_)
print(lasso_coeff)

# The above set of lines will force the coefficients to positive.
```

Answer (score 0):

Lasso does not solve the `l0`-penalized least squares but instead `l1`-penalized least squares. The solution you get for `alpha=0.01` is the Lasso solution (with a single non zero coef of ~0.245 for feature #10).

Even if your solution has a squared reconstruction error of `0.0`, it still has a penalty of `1.0` (multiplied by alpha).

The solution for lasso with `alpha=1.0` has a small squared reconstruction error of `0.04387` (divided by `2 * n_samples == 6`) and a smaller `l1` penalty of `0.245` (multiplied by alpha).

The objective function minimized by lasso is given in the docstring:

http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.Lasso.html

To summarize the different priors (or penalties) commonly used to regularize least squares regression:

- `l2` penalty favors any number of non-zero coefficients but with very
  small absolute values (close to zero)
- `l1` penalty favors a small number of non-zero coefficients with
  small absolute values.
- `l0` favors a small number of non zero coefficients of any absolute
  value.

`l0` being non-convex, it is often not as easy to optimize as `l1` and `l2`. This is why people use `l1` (lasso) or `l1 + l2` (elastic net) in practice to find sparse solutions even if not as clean as `l0`.